# biblatex style with multiple bibliographies in one document

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

This is to all the biblatex gurus.

I have only just come from Bibtex to Biblatex and I think I am lost in the many options available. Here is my scenario: I have a document, thesis which I intend to have two bibliographies with different styles..eventually. although for now I just want to get things working. With the working example below, I have the two bibliographies as I want but some things are not clear easy to solve:
1) The intext (textcite) outputs : LastName, Initials et.al but I would like LastName et.al.
2) The bibliography style outputs: FirsAuthorLastName, FirstAuthorInitials, SecondAuthorLastName, SecondAuthorInitials, etc but as you can see there is a comma separating both first and lastname as well as between authors. Now that doesn't look too nice I think. Perhaps a different marker like a semi column. Second, I want to list only the first few (5) authors and no more in the bibbliography style
3) Items in the second bibliography are also included in the first ? This is not too bad but 
4) The numbering continues in the second bibliography instead of restaring back at 1
5) Finally, is I need to have the second bibliography in a different style, say author-year, sorted by year of publication what do I do ?

Now this is asking too much but if others have solved these issues I will be glad to know.

Thank you.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mymwe.bib}
@ARTICLE{Rauchfuss2008,
  author = {Barton, Bryan E. and Olsen, Matthew T. and Rauchfuss, Thomas B.},
  title = {Aza- and Oxadithiolates Are Probable Proton Relays in Functional
    Models for the [FeFe]-Hydrogenases},
  journaltitle = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year = {2008},
  volume = {130},
  pages = {16834-16835},
  number = {50},
  doi = {10.1021/ja8057666},
}

@BOOK{Clegg1998,
  title = {Crystal Structure Determination},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  year = {1998},
  author = {Clegg, William},
  isbn = {978-0-19-855901-6},
  location = {Oxford, U.K.},
}
% This file was created with JabRef 2.6.
% Encoding: UTF8

@ARTICLE{Chen2011,
  author = {Guanying Chen and Tymish Y Ohulchanskyy and Wing Cheung Law and Hans
    Agren and Paras N Prasad},
  title = {Monodisperse NaYbF(4)?:?Tm(3+)/NaGdF(4) core/shell nanocrystals with
    near-infrared to near-infrared upconversion photoluminescence and
    magnetic resonance properties.},
  journal = {Nanoscale},
  year = {2011},
  month = {Mar},
  __markedentry = {[Theodore]},
  doi = {10.1039/c0nr01018a},
  institution = {Institute for Lasers, Photonics, and Biophotonics, The State University
    of New York at Buffalo, Buffalo, New York 14260, USA. tyo2@buffalo.edu
    pnprasad@buffalo.edu.},
  language = {eng},
  medline-pst = {aheadofprint},
  pmid = {21373678},
  timestamp = {2011.03.15},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/c0nr01018a}
}

@ARTICLE{Ding2011a,
  author = {Hong Ding and Ken-Tye Yong and Wing-Chueng Law and Indrajit Roy and
    Rui Hu and Fang Wu and Weiwei Zhao and Kun Huang and Folarin Erogbogbo
    and Earl J Bergey and Paras N Prasad},
  title = {Non-invasive tumor detection in small animals using novel functional
    Pluronic nanomicelles conjugated with anti-mesothelin antibody.},
  journal = {Nanoscale},
  year = {2011},
  month = {Mar},
  __markedentry = {[Theodore]},
  doi = {10.1039/c1nr00001b},
  institution = {The Institute for Lasers, Photonics and Biophotonics (ILPB), Department
    of Chemistry, The State University of New York at Buffalo, Buffalo,
    NY 14260, United States. pnprasad@buffalo.edu.},
  language = {eng},
  medline-pst = {aheadofprint},
  pmid = {21365120},
  timestamp = {2011.03.15},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/c1nr00001b}
}

@ARTICLE{Ding2011,
  author = {Hong Ding and Ken-Tye Yong and Indrajit Roy and Rui Hu and Fang Wu
    and Lingling Zhao and Wing-Cheung Law and Weiwei Zhao and Wei Ji
    and Liwei Liu and Earl J Bergey and Paras N Prasad},
  title = {Bioconjugated PLGA-4-arm-PEG branched polymeric nanoparticles as
    novel tumor targeting carriers.},
  journal = {Nanotechnology},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {22},
  pages = {165101},
  number = {16},
  month = {Apr},
  __markedentry = {[Theodore]},
  doi = {10.1088/0957-4484/22/16/165101},
  institution = {Department of Chemistry, Institute for Lasers, Photonics and Biophotonics,
    University at Buffalo, The State University of New York, Buffalo,
    NY 14260, USA. Department of Pharmaceutical Sciences, University
    at Buffalo, The State University of New York, Buffalo, NY 14260,
    USA.},
  language = {eng},
  medline-pst = {ppublish},
  pii = {S0957-4484(11)77811-4},
  pmid = {21393821},
  timestamp = {2011.03.15},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0957-4484/22/16/165101}
}

@ARTICLE{Pang2011,
  author = {Zhaoguang Pang and Xinping Zhang},
  title = {Direct writing of large-area plasmonic photonic crystals using single-shot
    interference ablation.},
  journal = {Nanotechnology},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {22},
  pages = {145303},
  number = {14},
  month = {Apr},
  __markedentry = {[Theodore]},
  doi = {10.1088/0957-4484/22/14/145303},
  institution = {Institute of Information Photonics Technology and College of Applied
    Sciences, Beijing University of Technology, Beijing 100124, People's
    Republic of China. College of Physics Science and Information Engineering,
    Hebei Normal University, Shi Jia Zhuang 050016, People's Republic
    of China.},
  language = {eng},
  medline-pst = {ppublish},
  pii = {S0957-4484(11)78366-0},
  pmid = {21346302},
  timestamp = {2011.03.15},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0957-4484/22/14/145303}
}

@ARTICLE{Zhai2011,
  author = {Tianrui Zhai and Xinping Zhang and Zhaoguang Pang and Fei Dou},
  title = {Direct Writing of Polymer Lasers Using Interference Ablation.},
  journal = {Adv Mater},
  year = {2011},
  month = {Mar},
  __markedentry = {[Theodore]},
  doi = {10.1002/adma.201100250},
  institution = {Institute of Information Photonics Technology and College of Applied
    Sciences, Beijing University of Technology, Beijing 100124, China.},
  language = {eng},
  medline-pst = {aheadofprint},
  pmid = {21374741},
  timestamp = {2011.03.15},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/adma.201100250}
}    
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=numeric-comp, sorting=none,defernumbers=true,backref=false,firstinits=true,terseinits=true,
            isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,eprint=false, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex} 
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first} 
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{mypubs}

\bibliography{mymwe}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is a sample text citing all others
\cite{Zhai2011,Pang2011,Ding2011,Ding2011a}
The filecontents stuff here is simply to generate a .bib file, and I've used \nocite{*} to include all references rather than selected citations. Said he \textcite{Chen2011}

\printbibliography[maxnames=99,title={References}]

\addtocategory{mypubs}{Ding2011,Ding2011a}
\nocite{Ding2011,Ding2011a}

\printbibliography[maxnames=99,category=mypubs,resetnumbers=true,omitnumbers=true,title={List of Publications}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You did notice [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/510), didn't you? `;-)`

`\textcite` output without initials: *Remove* the following code line in your example:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}
```

Semicolon as delimiter between authors:

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}% also removes "and" before last author
```

Only the first five author listed in the bibliography:

```
\printbibliography[maxnames=5,minnames=5]
```

As for your own publications also included in the general bibliography: This is exactly what you told biblatex to do. Also, restarting the second bibliography with `[1]` is bound to cause confusion. Rather try the following (with the preable option `defernumbers=true` enabled):

```
\printbibliography[category=mypubs,title={Own Publications}]
\printbibliography[notcategory=mypubs,title={Other References}]
```

Different style for the second bibliography, plus different sorting: Right now, I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: I didn't notice that post before. I have seen some of the options too in the biblatex manual. Thanks

Comment: Regarding the different style/sorting: the functionality for this is in biber now and will be enabled in biblatex in the not too distant future. It's likely that this will be biblatex 2.0 which will drop bibtex (program, not format) support.

Comment: @PLK Is there any news if this functionality has been already implemented, since I would also like to setup a second bibliography in my document for my own publications, where every item should start with the title instead of the usual author list.

Comment: The functionality for this is in biber but there is no interface implemented in biblatex yet. To move this up the priority list, I would open a feature request on the biblatex tracker on Sourceforge. There are a pile of really impressive new features coming in biblatex 2.0 which are all implemented in biber but the biblatex maintainer needs time to do the interfaces and documentation for biblatex. This is very time consuming and he'a busy man ...

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid I don't have *any* expertise with it, but I just happened to stumble across this: [bibunits](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/bibunits.html). Hope it might help.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but the `bibunits` package is for use with `natbib` not with `biblatex`.  `biblatex` provides all the functionality of `bibunits` and more, but the two packages are not compatible.

Comment: Good to know. I'm yet to need it, but cheers.