# Continuous multiple reference numbering

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to have three different sections for my references. Lets say `Reference1`, `References2` and `References3`. A custom ordering of my references. However, I want that the numbering of each Reference continues from the previous list. Lets say `References1` contains `1` to `100` reference. I need that `References2` that contain `20` references start from `101` to `120` and `References3` start from `121` to end. 
In my `LaTeX` I use the `biblatex` package.

Does anyone how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think, your question needs some clearification and a working (compilable) document as an example!

Answer (score 3):

Note: the answer below is valid for Biblatex/Biber as contained in TeX Live 2014 (and maybe some earlier versions as well). Starting with TeX Live 2015 a refsection is treated as a fully independent environment with a counter starting at 1, which is not influenced by `resetnumbers=false`. However, it does respect `resetnumbers=n`. Therefore, you can store the last number of a refsection and set the number in a new refsection to the stored number + 1.

Full credits go to @moewe for providing an implementation of this solution on https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1222.

Code (cf. full MWE in original answer below):

```
\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
Some text \autocite{B02,A01}.
\printbibliography[title={References1}]
\numgdef\resetnum{\csuse{blx@labelnumber@\therefsection}+1}
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}
Some more text \autocite{Z00,C03}
\printbibliography[title={References2}, resetnumbers=\resetnum]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

---

Original answer, valid for TeX Live 2014:

This can be done using `refsection`s, each containing a bibliography for the citations used in that `refsection`. The global option `sorting=none` for BibLaTeX results in references numbered in the order they appear in the text. The option `resetnumbers=false` for a `printbibliography` combined with the global option `defernumbers=true` results in continous numbering across `refsection`s. You may need to delete the `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, `.blg` files at some point if the result is not as expected.

MWE, adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42273/89417:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  keywords = {pub},
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@misc{Z00,
  keywords = {pub},
  author = {Zuthor, Z.},
  year = {2000},
  title = {Zulu},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
Some text \autocite{B02,A01}.
\printbibliography[title={References1},resetnumbers=true]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}
Some more text \autocite{Z00,C03}
\printbibliography[title={References2},resetnumbers=false]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or does this no longer work in TL 2021? With this MWE, I still get [1] and [2] in both refsections (yes, I have tried removing all temporary files).

Comment: @MårtenW indeed it does not seem to work anymore. `resetnumbers=3` in the second bibliography still works for this example, but of course that is not a good solution unless the document is completely finished and you know which number to use.

Comment: @MårtenW I added an issue on https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1222 to find out what is going on.

Comment: @MårtenW moewe kindly provided a solution on Github, see the edit to the answer above.