# Sorting of 2 bibliographies in biber (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, sorting, back-referencing

I have two bibliographies in my PhD thesis. One of them is my publications which should be sorted by the year in which they were published, the other one is the references which should be sorted in order of appearance.

I provide a minimal example. How can I implement that my publication list is sorted by date?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}

These are my publications. 

\begin{refsection}[publications.bib]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{refsection}


\newpage

These are the references of my PhD thesis. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I am aware that there is another article about stackexchange, but it didn't provide a clean answer and it is outdated:
[sorting multiple bibliographies in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42192/sorting-multiple-bibliographies-in-biblatex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `refsection` and `\newrefcontext` which allows you to change the sorting within a `refsection`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\autocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}
\newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]
\autocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography[title={Publications List}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Maybe it is worth noting that for the first refsection sorting=none sorts the reference list by order of appearance. Otherwise this did not work for me

Comment: @cerv21 Since you hadn't specified a sort order in your example, I assumed you wanted the default (which is not `none`, but `nty` (name, title, year).)